# Autoencoder to convert 2d to 3d layers ambiguity

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

i got around some references and research papers and taking idea from one of them i thought to go ahead and implement the same the image reference-[image]

So, here we are inputing a 2d input and the model outputs a 3d model of the same.
The network code which i have written is as follows:

**Edit**

```py
image = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))

# Encoder
l1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides = (2), padding='same', activation='leaky_relu')(image)  
l2 = MaxPooling2D()(l1)
l3 = Conv2D(32, (5,5), strides = (2), padding='same', activation='leaky_relu')(l2)
l4 = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(l3)
l5 = Conv2D(16, (7,7), strides = (2), padding='same', activation='leaky_relu')(l4)
l6 = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(l5)
l7 = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), strides = (2), padding = 'same', activation = 'leaky_relu')(l6)
l8 = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(l7)
l9 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), strides = (2), padding = 'same', activation = 'leaky_relu')(l8)
l10 = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(l9)
l11 = Conv2D(2, (4, 4), strides = (2), padding = 'same', activation = 'leaky_relu')(l10)
l12 = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(l11)
l13 = Conv2D(1, (2, 2), strides = (2), padding = 'same', activation = 'leaky_relu')(l12)

# latent variable z
l14 = Reshape((60,512))(l13)
print(l14.shape)#-->output=(None, 60, 512)
l15 = Dense((512), activation = 'leaky_relu')(l14)
print(l15.shape) #-->output=(None, 60, 512)
l16 = Dense((128), activation = 'leaky_relu')(l15)
print(l16.shape)#-->output=(60, 128)
l17 = Reshape((60,128))(l16)
print(l17.shape) #-->output=(60, 128)

#Decoder
l18 = UpSampling3D(size = (3,3,3))(l17) #-->throws error->IndexError: list index out of range
l19 = Conv3DTranspose(60, (8, 8, 8), strides = (64), padding='same', activation = 'leaky_relu') (l17)
l20 = UpSampling3D((3,3,3))(l19)
l21 = Conv3DTranspose(60, (16,16,16), strides =(32), padding='same', activation = 'leaky_relu')(l20)
l22 = UpSampling3D((3,3,3))(l21)
l23 = Conv3DTranspose(60, (32, 32, 32), strides = (32), padding='same', activation = 'lealy_relu')(l22)
l24 = UpSampling3D((3,3,3))(l23)
l25 = Conv3DTranspose(60, (64, 64, 64), strides = (24), padding='same', activation = 'leaky_relu')(l24)
l26 = UpSampling3D((3,3,3))(l25)
l27 = Conv3DTranspose(60, (64, 64, 64), strides = (1), padding='same', activation = 'leaky_relu')(l26)

model3D = Model(image, l27)
```

This is giving me endless errors i solved some initially and seems to get stuck at this one really bad!!
the error persists at l17, and says:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/907378238.py in <module>
     27 
     28 #Decoder
---> 29 l18 = UpSampling3D(size = (3,3,3))(l17) #-->throws error->IndexError: list index out of range
     30 l19 = Conv3DTranspose(60, (8, 8, 8), strides = (64), padding='same', activation = 'leaky_relu') (l17)
     31 l20 = UpSampling3D((3,3,3))(l19)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    975     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    976       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 977                                                 input_list)
    978 
    979     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1113       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1114       outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1115           inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1116 
   1117       if outputs is None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    846       return tf.nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    847     else:
--> 848       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    849 
    850   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    886           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    887           inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
--> 888           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    889 
    890         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in call(self, inputs)
   2720   def call(self, inputs):
   2721     return backend.resize_volumes(
-> 2722         inputs, self.size[0], self.size[1], self.size[2], self.data_format)
   2723 
   2724   def get_config(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py in resize_volumes(x, depth_factor, height_factor, width_factor, data_format)
   3215     output = repeat_elements(x, depth_factor, axis=1)
   3216     output = repeat_elements(output, height_factor, axis=2)
-> 3217     output = repeat_elements(output, width_factor, axis=3)
   3218     return output
   3219   else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py in repeat_elements(x, rep, axis)
   3248   x_shape = x.shape.as_list()
   3249   # For static axis
-> 3250   if x_shape[axis] is not None:
   3251     # slices along the repeat axis
   3252     splits = tf.split(value=x,

IndexError: list index out of range```
```

At this point i seem to be directionless, any help would be really appreciated. thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 1):

The shape of `l16` is:

```
l16.shape
TensorShape([None, 60, 8192])
```

and now you want to change the shape [60, 8192] into a shape [4,4,4,128] with the call `Reshape((4,4,4,128))(l16)`. But 60 * 8192 = 491520 and 4 * 4 * 4 * 128 = 8192. So those two shapes are incompatible (491520 != 8192). That's why the error message correctly states:

````
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [60, 8192], output_shape = [4, 4, 4, 128]```
````

The total number of cells must be the same before and after a reshape. E.g., you can change a (4,) tensor into a (2,2) tensor, but not e.g. into a (3,2) tensor.

The origin lies with `l14`, which you give the shape [60, 512]:

```
l14.shape
TensorShape([None, 60, 512])
```

Now, when you apply a `Dense` layer to a 2-dim shape like this, ***it will be applied to the last dimension***, i.e. the first dimension of the shape stays the same. That is why `l15` still has the shape [60, 512]:

```
l15.shape
TensorShape([None, 60, 512])
```

Similarly, `l16` will have a shape [60, 128 * 4 * 4 * 4] = [60, 8192]. Then, this is the input into the line for `l17` where `Reshape` chokes as explained above.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for such a valuable explaination i did some fixes in the network and the latent variable layers throws no errors, but the error comes under the dedcoder saying the list out of range in the upsampling3d layers...i have searched all over the internet and have used a number of hacks but nothing seems to work out...!!!

Comment: I thoroughly answered your question. But now you change your question completely so my answer becomes useless for anyone who reads this. If you have further questions, ask new questions, but don't spoil this one.

Comment: Oh, alright Frank will try to post this problem in a new question. Thanks btw